# emulator: ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting

Tags: android, android-emulator

> [2011-02-09 23:59:11 - Timerproject] ------------------------------
>   [2011-02-09 23:59:11 - Timerproject] Android Launch!
>   [2011-02-09 23:59:11 - Timerproject] adb is running normally.
>   [2011-02-09 23:59:11 - Timerproject] Performing acarin.timetracker.project.ezhil.Timerproject activity launch
>   [2011-02-09 23:59:11 - Timerproject] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'MA_AVD_2.3.1' is not available. Launching new emulator.
>   [2011-02-09 23:59:11 - Timerproject] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MA_AVD_2.3.1'
>   [2011-02-09 23:59:31 - Timetracker] New emulator found: emulator-5554
>   [2011-02-09 23:59:31 - Timetracker] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
>   [2011-02-10 00:01:40 - Timetracker] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
>   [2011-02-10 00:01:40 - Timetracker] Uploading Timetracker.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   [2011-02-10 00:01:40 - Timetracker] Installing Timetracker.apk...
>   [2011-02-10 00:04:11 - Timetracker] Failed to install Timetracker.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
>   [2011-02-10 00:04:11 - Timetracker] (null)
>   [2011-02-10 00:04:11 - Timetracker] Launch canceled!

---

i run the Timerproject but another timetrack project is only running the same timetracker project also doest responding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just close the already running emulator and start a new emulator more over if that doesn't works too close the eclipse too

Comment: i did wt u say .... Error:The application Timetracker(process acarin.timetracker.com)has stoped unexpectedly.please try again

Comment: This problem is related to your project not emulator or SDK your application is crashing due to some problem

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Eclipse, and you've started the app from within (using Run As->Android App), then it should reuse the existing AVD. If it can't find it, then it will try to start another emulator and fail with the error you're seeing. Check the system Path environment variable and make sure it's including the SDK directory. If it doesn't then you'll see this error (I had the same problem; turned out I misspelled Program Files as Program Fiiles).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt browse your adb path like

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

type the command

```
adb kill-server && adb start-server
```

this will resolve your problem